# How to use GL react native createComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning to use `gl-react-native` to apply image transformations on a react native project. I'm trying to implement one of the samples in [**this documentation**](https://github.com/gre/gl-react-v2/blob/master/docs/examples/2.md) but the app errors out with the following message.

> GL.Node elements can only be used as children of GL.Surface/GL.Node
>   and should not be rendered.

Following the documentation, I create the GL component with:

```
module.exports = GL.createComponent(
  ({ factor, image }) => <GL.Node shader={shaders.saturation} uniforms={{ factor, image }}/>,
{ displayName: "Saturation" });
```

If I remove this code and simply create a `GL.Node` in my `render()` method, the app is successful and the node renders correctly as in:

```
<Surface width={511} height={841}>
   <GL.Node shader={shaders.myShader} /> /* just an example shader that would work */
</Surface>
```

But when I try to define a GL component the app breaks. Could there be a parsing error preventing `<GL.Node>` from being used in `GL.createComponent`? I'm completely stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Surface } from "gl-react-native";

const GL = require("gl-react");
const shaders = GL.Shaders.create({
  saturation: {
    frag: `
precision highp float;
varying vec2 uv;
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform float factor;

void main () {
  vec4 c = texture2D(image, uv);
  // Algorithm from Chapter 16 of OpenGL Shading Language
  const vec3 W = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vec3(dot(c.rgb, W)), c.rgb, factor), c.a);
}
    `
  }
});

module.exports = GL.createComponent(
  ({ factor, image }) => <GL.Node shader={shaders.saturation} uniforms={{ factor, image }}/>,
{ displayName: "Saturation" });

export default class Background extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Surface width={511} height={841}>
        <Saturation
          factor={saturationFactor}
          image="http://i.imgur.com/iPKTONG.jpg"
        />
      </Surface>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module.exports` does not seem to work. Instead I set the component to a `const`.

The following GL component definition works for me:

```
const Saturation = GL.createComponent(
  ({ factor, image }) => <GL.Node shader={shaders.saturation} uniforms={{ factor, image }}/>,
{ displayName: "Saturation" });
```